# How to create a simple custom shortcode in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a folder in the `/wp-content/plugins` directory called customshortcode. The [add_shortcode command](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) should link the shortcode with the function.

In `/wp-content/plugins/customshorcode/` I created 2 files: `main.php` and `test.php`

Contents of main php is:

```
<?php require_once('../../../wp-includes/shortcodes.php'); ?>

<?php function custom_shortcode_func() {
  include_once('test.php');
}

add_shortcode('customshortcode','custom_shortcode_func');

?>
```

And test.php simply displays a division block:

```
<style>.testdiv{border:1px solid black; width:300px; heigh:300px;}</style>

<div class="testdiv"></div>
```

I first run the `/wp-content/plugins/customshorcode/main.php` file to see no errors and simple white screen. I assumed the short-code should be saved.

But when I enter [customshortcode] in the page, I don't get the division displayed, instead the text [customshortcode] instead.

I think I somehow need to link the page type to the plugin or something like that. Could you help me out?

Comment: Where and How you add  [customshortcode] in the page ?

Comment: in your `test.php` write: `return '<style>.testdiv{border:1px solid black; width:300px; heigh:300px;}</style><div class="testdiv"></div>';`. And why you have include `/wp-includes/shortcodes.php`??

Comment: Because without it when I got to the main.php to run it in the URL bar, I get: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_shortcode() in C:\MAMP\htdocs\new\wp-content\plugins\customshortcode\main.php on line 8

Comment: Also is in test.php do I need to open and close <?php ?> tags? Currently I only have the return statement  above without the tags.

Comment: @SamuelJMathew I simply created a new page, added a title, and put the shortcode in the content, clicked on preview page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `/wp-content/plugins/custom-short-code/main.php`

```
<?php
/*
* Plugin Name: Custom Short Code
* Description: Create your WordPress short code.
* Version: 1.0
* Author: <email>
*/

// Example 1 : WP short code to display form on any page or post.
function custom_short_code_func() {
?>
<style>
 .testdiv {
     border: 1px solid black;
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
 }
</style>

<div class="testdiv"></div>
<?php
}
add_shortcode('custom-short-code','custom_shortcode_func');
?>
```

Then enable the plugin

```
Custom Short Code
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great! I didn't know I had to create a plugin like this, I couldn't find it in documentation

Answer (score -1):

```
   <?php
/*
* Plugin Name: Custom ShortCodes
* Description: Create your WordPress plugin shortcodes.
* Version: 1.0
* Author: fatir031624@gmail.com
*/

function wpb_test_shortcode() { 
$message = 'Hello world!'; 
return $message;
} 
add_shortcode('testing', 'wpb_test_shortcode');
?>
```

Comment: Details answer in your visit website.URL:https://devndesigns.com/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).